# implementation of product method of List

Tags: scala

I want to see the implementation of 'product' method in class List in Scala. I checked in the following file but cannot see it.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala

The version of Scala I am running is 2.11.8 so I must be at the correct branch.

Where can I see how 'product' method is implemented?

Comment: Please be more specific with the problem you have. Show code examples you have problem with. thanks

Comment: the problem was that I couldn't find source code of product method. I wanted to study it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@product:A) and open the documentation of `product`, you can see that is says "Definition Classes". There you can see that it is defined by `GenTraversableOnce` and implemented by `TraversableOnce`. If you click through to the scaladoc of [TraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce), you find a link straight to the correct source file ("Source", under the summary of the class).

Answer (score 2):

It's defined in `TraversableOnce` and then `List` inherits it.

You can check the source [here.](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala)